# How to add Multi OnClickListener on button in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to add multi onclickListener On a button. Like if I click on Button1 then It will run `Log.i("first","first")` and then `Log.i("Second","Second")` but both `Log.i` not in one function/class.

Comment: Do you understand what the `View v` parameter passed to `onClick(View v)` is meant to be used for?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira how ? i dont think it will work..

Comment: @Squonk I m new in android so not much knowledge.

Comment: It's actually very unclear what you are trying to do. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: No need to much knowledge for this topic. It is base android development. Just do some search before writing here a question.

Comment: @user3783730, bit confused what you asked and what you expect, do you want two different button with two different log or single button showing two log

Answer (score 1):

You can just call it at the same time in onClick of your button:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        run1();
        run2();
    }
});
```

and your functions:

```
public void run1(){
    Log.i("first", "first");
}
public void run2(){
    Log.i("Second", "Second");
}
```